# Define and initialise this datatype in C programming

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef

Could someone let me know if this is the correct definition of this datatype and if the way I've initialised it is correct?

```
typedef int const * (* const DataOne)(const int *);
```

=> The above datatype shows a constant pointer to a function that takes a pointer to a constant `int` as a parameter and returns a pointer to a constant `int`.

=> initialised and declaration: `DataOne = &myFunction(7);`

Comment: myFunction(7) is a function call. Does it return a function pointer?

Comment: Thanks, is my explanation correct?

Comment: Is the last code snippet missing a variable for the pointer? It's `<type> = <initializer>;`.

Comment: took liberty in addding some related tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
typedef int const * (* const DataOne)(const int *);
```

> => the above datatype shows a constant pointer to a function that takes a pointer to a constant int as a parameter and returns a pointer to a constant int.

Correct.

> => initialised and declaration: DataOne = &myFunction(7);

Not correct. Function pointer assignment cannot be made on a function call (i.e. you cannot have any actual arguments for the parameters). Also, DataOne is a type, not a variable. So, it should look something like this:

```
int const * myFunction(const int*);
DataOne myPointer = myFunction;  // &myFunction would also work
```

To declare an equivalent function pointer without a type:

```
int const * myFunction(const int*);
int const * (* const functionPointer)(const int *) = myFunction;
```

Comment: Thanks, how can it be either with or without the ampersand on the myFunction?

Comment: @IamTrent With `&myFunction`, you are explicit that you want the function's address, but taking the function alone makes it turn into a pointer to the function. So both are equivalent.

Comment: Alos be consistent with your constant integers declaration : chose either `const int` or `int const`, mixing both can be quite confusing.